# Chrome extension to add javascript onto a live page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm going to be looking at adding some minor Jquery onto a specific page on my site to alter some layouts.

Id like a way to preview my script before i publish it. Was wondering if any chrome extensions exist that would allow me to load some new script into the browser so i can preview how the page looks straight away? (without doing any publishes etc)

I use one called MagiCSS for previewing on the fly changes to CSS, was hoping something similar existed for javascript.

So been trying the console as suggested

I seem to need to refresh the page before the code is actually executed (possibly because i am using the jQuery document.ready function) Once page is refreshed however i lose my code from the console (even though this executes). Am i doing this right? It seems like it will need a lot of back and forth to get this right

Comment: or just code in the console

Comment: code in the console? am i missing a trick here? how do i do that?

Comment: `F12` opens the Dev Tools, which comprehends the JS Console in which you can type live code and a bunch of CSS tools much more powerful than any plugin you may find around so you should use that for your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can open the Chrome debugger (by pressing `F12` key)
2. Go to console, type your code, and press `ENTER` to execute it.
3. If you want new lines in your code, press `SHIFT + ENTER`. (Pressing `ENTER` alone would execute your javascript code)